# Cloudinary C# "File name must be specified in UploadParams!"

Tags: c#, cloudinary

I'm working with cloudinary for keep my images in cloud. Following this [Article](https://cloudinary.com/documentation/dotnet_image_and_video_upload) for successfully update. I uploaded successfull once. After change my code somehow it doesn't work properly.

My Upload Method :

```
 var uploadParams = new ImageUploadParams
 {
     File = new FileDescription(imageDictionary[Consts.IMAGE_PATH]),
     UniqueFilename = false,
     UseFilename = true,
     PublicId = GetCloudinaryPublicId(imageDictionary[Consts.IMAGE_NAME]) 
 };

 ImageUploadResult? cloudUpdateResult;
 try
 {
     cloudUpdateResult = await _cloudinary.UploadAsync(uploadParams);
 }
 catch (Exception e)
 {
     return new ErrorResult(e.Message);
 }
```

Here `imageDictionary` returns image's physical path. For example  `wwwroot/images/userId/`

And setted `PublicId` for cloudinary folder structure. For example `images/userId/123123.jpg`

---

When i try to upload an image (which exist in physical path) `_cloudinary.UpdateAsync()` throws exception, returns this message : `"File name must be specified in UploadParams!"`

Comment: P.S. params doesn't have property like FileName or something.
Has FileNameOverride, and i also tried it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figure out that i'm giving just path to construstor `wwwroot/images/userId` and not giving imageName `123123.jpg`

After fixed it, it start work.

```
File = new FileDescription(imageDictionary[Consts.IMAGE_PATH] + imageDictionary[Consts.IMAGE_NAME]),
```